# Chart.js set global point size not working

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Hello im trying to reduce the point size of all the charts that i have, In the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/elements.html) it says to set by

```
Chart.defaults.global.elements.rectangle.radius = 2
```

But point sizes do not change, although it have made it to change size by setting it manually upon declaration, but it would be nice to do it globally since i have to dynamically change at some stage in the website

Related code is below:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    //Some looong data here
});

var ctx2 = document.getElementById('myChart2').getContext('2d');
var myChart2 = new Chart(ctx2, {
    //Some looong data here
});

var ctx3 = document.getElementById('myChart3').getContext('2d');
var myChart3 = new Chart(ctx3, {
    //Some looong data here
});

Chart.defaults.global.elements.rectangle.radius = 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [global point options](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/elements.html#point-configuration) instead of [global rectangle options](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/elements.html#rectangle-configuration).

```
// Chart.defaults.global.elements.rectangle.radius = 2; // remove this line
Chart.defaults.global.elements.point.radius = 2;
```

> You also have to move this line on top of your code. It should be performed prior to create your charts.

Comment: Awesome it works! so i cant change it dynamically using the global approach later on ? will i have to manually set it for each graph after creating?

Comment: It is global and has to be defined once only.

Comment: For Chart.js 3 -- Namespace: `options.elements.point`, global point options: `Chart.defaults.elements.point` (no `global` in the namespace).